# Where to manage my Windows 8 synced machines?

Tags: windows-8, sync

I remember being able to go on the microsoft side and see all my synced Windows 8 devices but can't find that place anymore. For example, whenever you install Windows 8 on a new machine, during the installation, after you've signed in your microsoft account, it would ask you whether to sync this new machine with existing machines and there would be a list of my existing machines. Where should I go to manage those existing machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either mean:

this: https://onedrive.live.com/Options/DeviceBackups
or this: https://account.live.com/names/Manage